# YARRRML: How to link two entities by matching against specific value from JSON

Tags: knowledge-graph, rml-rdf, ontology-mapping

I have a JSON of the following form:

```
[
  {
    "crew":[
      {
        "id":123,
        "job":"Director",
        "name":"Director Testname",
      },
      {
        "id":456,
        "job":"Screenplay",
        "name":"Crew Testname",
      }
    ],
    "id":789
  }
```

The "id":862 represents a film. From the crew array I want to create a Directors class. Both should be linked through hasDirector.

My YARRRML.yaml looks like this:

```
prefixes:
  film: "http://example.com/film#"

mappings:
  films:
    sources:
      - ['data.json~jsonpath', '$.[*]']
    s: film:film$(id)
    po:
      - [a, film:Film]
      - p: film:hasDirector
        o:
          value: film:Director$(crew['?(@.job=="Director")'].id)
          type: iri
    
  
  directors:
    sources:
      - ['data.json~jsonpath', '$[*].crew[?(@.job == "Director")]']
    s: film:Director$(id)
    po:
     - [a, film:Director]
     - [film:fullName, $(name)]
```

This returns no mappings via hasDirector, but provides all Directors instances. I created through Matey the RML Mapping and with rmlmapper-java I've created the RDF.

Alternatively I've also tried:

```
 - p: film:hasDirector
    o:
      mapping: directors
      condition:
        function: equal
        parameters:
          - [str1, $(crew.id), s]
          - [str2, "Director", o]
```

This resulted in all entities in the crew array were linked to film as directors.

Has someone a solution how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first way it appears that JSONPath conditions just don't work in YARRRML (or at least I found no way of making them work in the object mapping).

For the second, you need to use the `condition` statement, imposing the equality on `.job` and reporting the `.id` when a positive match is found:

```yaml
      - p: f:hasDirector
        o: b:$(crew..id)~iri
        condition:
            function: equal
            parameters:
              - [str1, $(crew..job), s]
              - [str2, "Director", o]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I have to report the id. I modified it a bit further in order to create an IRI instead of a string:
- p: film:hasDirector
        o: 
          value: film:Director$(crew..id)
          type: iri
        condition:
            function: equal
            parameters:
              - [str1, $(crew..job), s]
              - [str2, "Director", o]

Comment: @lost_ds you're right, I've updated my answer accordingly with `~iri`.